# How to perform a CASE statement in an SQL SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

How do I perform an `IF...THEN` in an SQL SELECT statement?Can i change to `Case..then` to IF..THEN , i have some error in `Case..then`

```
DECLARE  @Display Varchar(10)   SET @Display = '210120'
DECLARE  @ret     Varchar(5)    SET @ret     = '12345'
DECLARE  @ret2    Varchar(5)    SET @ret2    = '6789'

DECLARE  @Custom2 Varchar(10)
SELECT (CASE 
          WHEN CHARINDEX(LEFT(@Display, 1),@ret) > 0 THEN
              SET @Custom2 = 'None'
          WHEN CHARINDEX(LEFT(@Display, 1),@ret2) > 0 THEN
              SET @Custom2 = @ret+'_'+@Display 
       END ) as Custom
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: don't try to set variables in the middle of a select query.

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that returns a **single, atomic value** - it's not a flow control *statement* that can handle code blocks and stuff like that.

Comment: Tip: A `CASE` expression may also have an `ELSE` clause to handle any unexpected data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mismatch of things going on here. You can't use a case expression to control flow like you are doing...but then you also sort of have this as a column. It is not totally clear what you are trying to do here but maybe this will help.

```
DECLARE  @Display Varchar(10)   SET @Display = '210120'
DECLARE  @ret     Varchar(5)    SET @ret     = '12345'
DECLARE  @ret2    Varchar(5)    SET @ret2    = '6789'

SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(LEFT(@Display, 1),@ret) > 0 THEN
              'None'
          WHEN CHARINDEX(LEFT(@Display, 1),@ret2) > 0 THEN
              @ret+'_'+@Display 
       END as Custom
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is slightly off, try this instead:

```
SELECT @Custom2 = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(LEFT(@Display, 1),@ret) > 0 
                       THEN 'None'
                  WHEN CHARINDEX(LEFT(@Display, 1),@ret2) > 0 
                       THEN @ret + '_' + @Display 
                  END As Custom
```